# How to properly host an HTTP proxy server

Tags: azure, go, proxy, hosting, http-proxy

I coded a simple HTTP proxy with Go. I've
tested and confirmed that it works locally,
but I'm having issues with deployment.

I deployed on Render and Azure. I also set the
"http only" config on azure, both deployments
seem to work correctly as normal web apps (they
accept and process http requests correctly)
but using any as a proxy simply times out.

I don't think it's a Go specific issue,
because I also deployed a python sample
on Azure, and it yields the same problems.

GitHub link: https://github.com/namikaze-dev/proxi

Thanks for your time.

EDIT:
success from localhost:

```
curl -x http://localhost:8080 http://httpbin.org/ip
{
  "origin": "105.112.121.177"
}
```

error from remote deployment:

```
curl: (28) Failed to connect to delightful-mushroom-6a73af11705c422c9be38c2fbdbc51b4.azurewebsites.net port 1080: Timed out
```

Comment: The proxy is not reachable since there are firewalls in the way. With cloud setups you usually need to explicitly configure the firewalls in your setup to allow access on uncommon ports like 1080.

Comment: I see,  I'll take a look at my setup and see if I can figure something out. Thanks.